# Drag and drop - not drop out of droppable

Tags: jquery

I have a project `drag and drop + clone + resizable`, so far I've managed to do everything right.
I can clone an element and this element can be resized (resizable)

However, the problem is :
 
I clone elements and game area are droppable and may leave the area and stay droppable across the screen (they can only be cloned when the game element droppable area but after being cloned they can be dragged around the screen)
I wonder if there's any way to make that they can only be dragged within the droppable area, can not leave the droppable

PS: sorry if the English is wrong, I'm using google translator..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery-ui its possible. Just use `containment` with selector on your area. Check this [example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) for more information.

Comment: If im correctly understand you, you need to add `containment` condition to new element? Then, when you are cloning new element, give him unique id and run `$( "#new_id" ).draggable({ containment: "#container" });`. Should work.